# Using statement OR Function exit to dispose/kill a resource?

Tags: .net

Should I ALWAYS use this practice...

```
Public Function DoWork()

    Using dc as New myDataContext()

        ...

    End Using

End Function
```

or is just exiting the function good enough and do the same thing?

```
Public Function DoWork()

    Dim dc as New myDataContext()

    ...

End Function
```

Does exiting the End Function do the same as End Using in terms of disposing of the DataContext resource?

Comment: I never programmed in .NET, yet I know the answer because that topic comes up three times a week. Does the average .NET programmer know this little about his language?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're completely different.

If the object implements [`IDisposable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) then you should always aim to dispose it - the easiest way being to wrap it in a [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) block.

(And if the object doesn't implement [`IDisposable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) then you can't dispose it or use [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) anyway, even if you wanted to.)

Comment: How would you handle a scenario when you're in a Using block inside of a Function and you need to call Exit Function inside a For/Next Loop or something?

Comment: The `using` block will handle that situation for you. It basically translates to a `try...finally` where the `finally` block will ensure that `Dispose` is called on your object.

Comment: @EdenMachine Why would that be a problem? The object will disposed when you leave the scope of the `using` statement even if you return from the function or throw an exception. It only will not be executed in case of a catastrophic failure(OutOfMemory,...)

Comment: For example, does this defeat the purpose of the using?    
    
    Public Function GetAllUsers() As IList(Of User)    
        Using dc As New myDataContext()    
            Return (From u In dc.Users).ToList()    
        End Using    
    End Function

Comment: That code is perfectly fine. It creates and fills the list, and then disposes the data-context.

Comment: Ahh - so as long as you are in a using, if you exit the using for ANY reason like with Exit Function or Return in a function (except for catastrophic failure) then the resources will be disposed of?

Comment: I was initially under the impression that you had to hit the "End Using" line for any of that disposal to take place.

Comment: Exactly. It will be disposed no matter how you exit the functions (except catastrophes)

Comment: If by "catastrophe," you mean throwing an exception, then this is incorrect. The `using` statement will dispose of the resource *even if an exception is thrown*.

Comment: @Cody By catastrophe I mean OutOfMemoryException, StackOverflowException, forced app-domain, evil native code stuff, power loss,... but not normal exceptions.

Answer (score 4):

The purpose of the [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) statement is to invoke [`Dispose`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose.aspx) on an object that implements [`IDisposable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx). The manual way to do that is a `try...finally` statement, but that's much uglier.

Exiting the function does not invoke `Dispose`. The local variable goes out of scope and doesn't reference the object anymore. That an object has no references anymore causes no immediate reaction. It just means that the GC *may* collect it from now on.

So the native resources will linger until the GC collects them, possible much later. Or if there are other references to that object which would have been removed inside `Dispose` it might not even get collected at all.

[Using statement in the VB.net specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx)

And in C#(VB.net should be very similar) `using` on a reference type corresponds to:

```
{
   ResourceType resource = expression;
   try {
      statement;
   }
   finally {
      if (resource != null) ((IDisposable)resource).Dispose();
   }
}
```

As you see the `finally` takes care of calling dispose no matter what happens in `statement`. Finally is executed even if you exit the function, or throw an exception.
Just a few catastrophic errors like OutOfMemory, StackOverflow and forced app-domain unload will not execute it.

Comment: And this can result in out of memory or connection pool timeouts.